# USB Drive Format Error

Tags: partitioning, gparted, format

I am trying to format my 19GB usb drive. I am currently using gedit.

```
sudo gparted
```

It works, but with a nasty error.

```
(gpartedbin:7382): GLib-CRITICAL **: Source ID 7 was not found when attempting to remove it

(gpartedbin:7382): GLib-CRITICAL **: Source ID 6 was not found when attempting to remove it

(gpartedbin:7382): GLib-CRITICAL **: Source ID 26 was not found when attempting to remove it

(gpartedbin:7382): GLib-CRITICAL **: Source ID 25 was not found when attempting to remove it
Error fsyncing/closing /dev/sdb: Remote I/O error
```

When I keep pressing Ignore, I get to the main screen.
Switch to /dev/sdb and create a new primary partition.

[This is the "Save Details" of Gparted](http://pastebin.com/2BD5K5wx)

What should I do?

Comment: Have you tried to specify the drive on the command line? `sudo gparted /dev/sdb`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DO NOT USE GPARTED FIRST OFF (Its only good for live cd/usb to install the os, IMHO)

Insert USB

Verify the OS recognizes it by opening nautilus

Close nautilus

Click Super Key (windows key on most keyboards)

Search for 'disks'

Select 'disks'

Select correct volume in the left column  (Should say usb flash)

Click 'more settings' in the top right of the window (looks like this) [image]

Select 'format' option

Click 'format' button

The default format settings should be fine (quick and compatible with all systems)

If you think the flash drive has corrupt sectors you may want to do a 'slow'(full) format